# Create reportviewer from dataset

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am reading a file from which I create a dataset and I need to create a report from that dataset but this code is not working. so maybe someone could tell me what I am doing wrong I would really apreciated it or suggest another approach to this issue.

The BuildataSet function is working properly, creating the report its whats giving me problems.

```
public DataSet BuildDataSet(string file,string tableName,string delimeter)
{
  //create our DataSet
  DataSet domains = new DataSet();
   //add our table
   domains.Tables.Add(tableName);
    String c =    "VOYAGE|SAILDATE|DELIVERYDATE|AMENITY|QTY|COMPLIMENTS|MESSAGE|CABIN|1STPAXNAME|"
    +"1STPAXLAST|2NDPAXNAME|2NDPAXLAST|3RDPAXNAME|3RDPAXLAST|4THPAXNAME|4THPAXLAST|SHIP|TYPE|DELIVERYTYPE|DROOM|SEATING|TABLE|GHOSTCOLUMN";

try
{
    //first make sure the file exists
    if (File.Exists(file))
    {
        //create a StreamReader and open our text file
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(file);

        //read the first line in and split it into columns
        string [] columns = c.Split('|');
        //now add our columns (we will check to make sure the column doesnt exist before adding it)
        foreach (string col in columns)
        {
            //variable to determine if a column has been added
            bool added = false;
            string next = "";
            //our counter
            int i = 0;
            while (!(added))
            {
                string columnName = col;


                    //now check to see if the column already exists in our DataTable
                    if (!(domains.Tables[tableName].Columns.Contains(columnName)))
                    {
                        //since its not in our DataSet we will add it
                        domains.Tables[tableName].Columns.Add(columnName, typeof(string));
                        added = true;
                    }//end if
                    else
                    {
                        //we didnt add the column so increment out counter

                        i++;
                        next = "_" + i.ToString();
                        break;
                    }//end else


             }
        }
        //now we need to read the rest of the text file
        string data = reader.ReadToEnd();

        //now we will split the file on the carriage return/line feed
        //and toss it into a string array
        string [] rows = data.Split("\r".ToCharArray());
        //now we will add the rows to our DataTable
        foreach (string r in rows)
        {
            string[] items = r.Split(delimeter.ToCharArray());
            //split the row at the delimiter
            //for (int i = 0; i <= items.Count() - 1; i++)
            //{

                domains.Tables[tableName].Rows.Add(items);

            //}
        }
    }
    else
    {
        throw new FileNotFoundException("The file " + file + " could not be found");
    }

}
catch (FileNotFoundException ex)
{
    _message = ex.Message;
    return null;
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    _message = ex.Message;
    return null;
}

//now return the DataSet
 return domains;
```

}
     //#endregion

```
   protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{



    DataSet ds = BuildDataSet(@"C:/Documents/GIFTCDS.TXT", "MyNewTable", "|");
    GridView1.DataSource = ds;
    GridView1.DataBind();


    ReportDataSource rds = new ReportDataSource("MyNewTable", ds.Tables[0]);
    ReportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Clear();
    ReportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(rds);
    ReportViewer1.DataBind();
    ReportViewer1.LocalReport.Refresh();


}
```

Comment: Do you need to set the report:   MyReportViewer.LocalReport.ReportPath = "MyReport.rdlc";

Comment: i added that and i still don't get any report to display..thank you anyways

Comment: Are you getting any errors?  What if you create a report with no data, maybe just some text, can you display that?

Comment: no i am not getting any errors . i am able to see the report layout but no data inside

Comment: If you bind the datatable to a GridView do you see the data?  (just a sanity check).

Comment: yeah when i bind it to the gridview i can see the whole table i have in the dataset

Comment: Maybe you are missing this step: "When you convert a server report definition (.rdl) file to a client report definition (.rdlc), you must ensure that your application includes data binding code for the ReportViewer control. The data binding code is generated automatically when you create a .rdlc file from a report template. However, the data binding code will be missing if you create the .rdlc file in some other way. To add the data binding code, use the Choose Data Sources task on the ReportViewer Tasks smart tags panel."   http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms252085%28v=VS.80%29.aspx